# What is the minimal model of $E:y^2=x^3-x-n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Does it hold that $E:y^2=x^3-x-n$ is a minimal model for any choice $n$? Using the Sage programming language we can check that $E$ is indeed minimal for every $n\leq20,000$.

Comment: The sentence starting with "Obviously" is incorrect. If you want to change your equation with $p$, the term in front of $x$ would be divided by $p^4$. This means that your equation is minimal except maybe at $2$ and $3$. For those you have to look at Tate's algorithm. From experiments with small $n$, I guess that the answer will be that the equation is indeed globally minimal.

Comment: It is minimal (indeed good) at 3, as the discriminant is $\Delta=-2^4(27n^2-4)$ so $v_3(\Delta)=0$. Similarly, $v_2(\Delta)\le 7$ implies minimality at 2.

Comment: @user171793 Thank you for your comment; could you write it up as an answer so I can upvote and accept it?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I removed the "obviously" portion because I realized that my "obvious" argument was flat out incorrect

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I don't quite understand your comment; Could you restate it as an answer?

Comment: My answer for $p>3$ and user171793's answer for $2$ and $3$ show that the equation is minimal. It is a consequence of Tate's algorithm that if $v(\Delta)<12$ then the equation is minimal at $v$; that is all that is needed from the algorithm. You may still want to learn about it - as explained in Silverman's second book.